# How can extract css from nuxt version3 in build stage

Tags: css, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxt3

When I build my project then I see All of Styles used in my code "inline" (in production mode)
important: my nuxt verion is 3

I try with `nuxt generate` & `nuxt build` & `npm run build` & `npm run generate` & `nuxi build`

and I use this codes in my nuxt.config.js :

```
build: {
    css: {
      extract: true,
    },
  },
```

OR

```
 webpack: {
      extractCSS: true,
      optimization: {
        splitChunks: {
          cacheGroups: {
            styles: {
              name: 'styles',
              test: /\.(css|vue)$/,
              chunks: 'all',
              enforce: true
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

OR

```
build: {
    extractCSS: true,
  },
  webpack: {
    extractCSS: true,
  },
  buildModouls:{
    extractCSS: true,
  },
```

So do not extracted my css codes!! Why? How can fix it?
there are worked for nuxt2 and not working for nuxt3

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me:

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  ...
   experimental: {
     inlineSSRStyles: false,
   },
  ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem

in nuxt.config ts you need to set `builder:"webpack"` and write your config in webpack section f.e.

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  builder:"webpack",
  css:["~~/assets/sass/_index.scss"],// your css
  webpack: {
    extractCSS: true,
    optimization: {
      splitChunks: {
        cacheGroups: {
          styles: {
            name: 'styles',
            test: /\.(css|vue)$/,
            chunks: 'all',
            enforce: true
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
experimental: {
inlineSSRStyles: false,
extractCSS: true,
```

Nuxt 3